# How to restrict a parameter pack for a variadic template's parameter field to be of a specific type

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

This is a continuation off of this original question here: [Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993864/variadic-template-parameter-pack-to-accept-only-unsigned-ints-or-size-t-as-its-t) that was focused more towards a design decision. This question is more to the actual how to towards the implementation if it can even be done.

I have this in my current source:

```
template <typename ClassType,typename... Dimensions>
class DimensionPack {
public: 
    typename std::tuple<ClassType, std::tuple<Dimensions...> >::type Dim;
    const unsigned int numarguments = sizeof...(Dimensions);
};
```

That would be used with a series of classes that are related with the following prototypes:

```
template<typename ClassType, typename... Args>  class MatrixReference;
template<typename ClassType, typename... Args>  class MatrixStorage;
template<typename ClassType, typename... Args>  class MatrixAllocation;
```

I have already been asked why couldn't I just use `std::size_t...`

After considerable thought I'm still leaning towards using the variadic parameter pack with the helper template that would store it into an `std::tuple` to help pack and unpack the parameters. Also I have a need to test these parameters to be in the range of `{x; x > 0}` so they must all be + integers. So the parameter pack itself or the contents of it can be either `std::size_t` or `unsigned int` but they all need to be one or the other. I also need to test these parameters to check if their value is even or odd and to save those results into a container. The use of a helper function will do that for me.

Knowing this I'm leaning towards staying with the parameter pack so I can easily pass that pack as a reference from one template to another since the set of these templates will work together, and I can also pass the parameter pack to my helper function to test for odd and even values.

So the questions become:

- Can a parameter pack with `<typename... Args>` be restricted to a specific type such as `std::size_t` or `unsigned int`?
- If so, how can this be done?
- If not what are my options towards achieving this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variadic template parameter pack to accept only unsigned ints or size\_t as its type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993864/variadic-template-parameter-pack-to-accept-only-unsigned-ints-or-size-t-as-its-t)

Comment: O'Neil I added that it was a continuation of the first question, however instead of making a choice between one or the other; I'm asking here if it is possible and if so how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659127/restrict-variadic-template-arguments/39659128#39659128 Although that is about function parameters, the concepts there can be easily applied to your case.

Comment: I propose to close the Original Question, keeping it as a reference for historical purposes and to accept this question as the actual question at hand.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Questions are both yours, so you are free to do that.

Answer (score 2):

> Can a parameter pack with  be restricted to a specific type such as std::size_t or unsigned int?

The bool trick does it in a compact way.
As a minimal, working example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename... Args>
constexpr bool check(Args&&...) {
    return std::is_same<
        std::integer_sequence<bool, true, (std::is_same<std::size_t, std::remove_reference_t<Args>>::value or std::is_same<unsigned int, std::remove_reference_t<Args>>::value)...>,
        std::integer_sequence<bool, (std::is_same<std::size_t, std::remove_reference_t<Args>>::value or std::is_same<unsigned int, std::remove_reference_t<Args>>::value)..., true>
    >::value;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(check(std::size_t{42}, 3u), "!");
    static_assert(not check(std::size_t{42}, 'c'), "!");
}
```

I used both the types in the check because of your comment (emphasis mine):

> So the parameter pack itself or the contents of it can be either std::size_t or unsigned int but **they all need to be one or the other**

See it running on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pHdL8SR4Ki6tmq9x).

Note that you can use the same technique to check statically the types used to initialize a class.
As an example:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct S {
    static_assert(std::is_same<
        std::integer_sequence<bool, true, (std::is_same<std::size_t, std::remove_reference_t<Args>>::value or std::is_same<unsigned int, std::remove_reference_t<Args>>::value)...>,
        std::integer_sequence<bool, (std::is_same<std::size_t, std::remove_reference_t<Args>>::value or std::is_same<unsigned int, std::remove_reference_t<Args>>::value)..., true>
    >::value, "!");
};
```

In this case, something like this will compile:

```
S<std::size_t, unsigned int> s;
```

On the other side, the following will end with an error at compile time:

```
S<std::size_t, char> s;
```